# I do not understand the properties of this Moebius doughnut

Tags: general-topology

Let us define a surface that consists of a 2D square in which the left edge is identified with right edge, but upside down, like in a Moebius strip, and the bottom is identified with the reversed top, with left and right switched.

1. Does this surface has a name? (I could not find anything)
2. Does it have one or two sides?
3. Is it uniform, like the Moebius strip, in the sense that someone inside the surface cannot tell where the surface has been cut and twisted? The reason I ask is because it seems to be the case that a line moving in a diagonal direction does not seem to reappear at the other side, but rather seems to fold on top of itself, as if being reflected. I am not sure if this is correct, I spent a lot of time making drawing to figure this out, but I am still not sure if I did it right. I have no knowledge of topology.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This surface is called the (real) protective plane, and is denoted $\mathbb{RP}^2$. It is non orientable like the Möbius strip - it only had one side.

Your final question is not clear to me, if by uniform you mean that every part of the surface looks like any other so looking at just at small patch you can't determine if it's a plane, a sphere, or anything else, then you are right. It is an example of a manifold, and after gluing the edges together, the four corners of the square look like any other part of the surface from a topological point of view.

Comment: Thanks, I am going to search it. I might have made some mistake, I concluded that a segment moving in a diagonal direction towards a corner would not reappear at th opposite corner but was actually "reflected" backwards, which would imply that a corner is different than a point inside. But I guess I got it wrong